# Algorithm for connecting geometric lines

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

I have n open geometric lines in 3D. which need to be joined into a single line based upon the criteria that minimum length of additional lines between the end points of the lines. Please suggest algorithm which have minimum complexity.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this sounds to me a bit like the Travelling Salesman problem.

Comment: Yes, sure sounds like it

Comment: In this case before solving that, you need to solve the Travelling Futureman problem to get the solution from the future.

Answer (score 1):

A best known algorithm runs in O(2<sup>n</sup>) time.
As Andrew Said in his comment, this is a more general version of traveling salesmen problem. If you find a better algorithm you'll be awarded a $1000000 prize.

You should try approximated solutions instead, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms).

Comment: Well, asking here is a first shot

Comment: @surana4u Yes, the wikipedia article I've pointed to have a large list of exact and non-exact solutions.